# Can I say "I am glad hearing from you" or it is wrong?

Tags: adjectives, gerunds

> I am glad hearing from you.

Is it correct?

And does it have a real meaning or it doesn't?

Answer (score 3):

You can, but it's relatively unusual: "glad to hear" is much more common.

A search in GlowBE (the corpus of Global Web-based English) shows 97 instances of "glad" following by an "-ing" verb (and some of those are irrelevant because of the idiom "glad handing"), against 21100 instances of "glad to [verb]"