# Why isn't "I'm glad to hearing from you" correct?

Tags: prepositions, ing

I have read in this forum that it isn't correct:
[Can I say "I am glad hearing from you" or it is wrong?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301122/can-i-say-i-am-glad-hearing-from-you-or-it-is-wrong)
but in this case "to" is a preposition followed by a verb and the -ing form for the verb should be used, according to my grammar english book, as it happens for "I'm looking forward to seeing you".
There is some inconsistence that I don't understand. Thanks

Comment: The question you quote is talking about something specifically different. It doesn't use **to** in its construction, and that sentence **is** correct. So, you *haven't* read that that version of the sentence is incorrect. In short, *I'm glad hearing from you* is not the same as *I am glad **to** hearing from you.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think grammar books say that you **always** use gerund after any 'to' :) . One thing is the phrasal verb 'to look forward to' which requires noun/gerund; the other - the adjective 'glad' which requires 'about', 'of', 'for', or an infinitive (hence 'to').

See: http://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=glad

So: 'glad to hearing' is incorrect because

1. if 'to' is a preposition, then it is a wrong one - 'glad about hearing' is correct
2. if 'to' is a part of an infinitive, it should be 'glad to hear'.

Comment: You could also say "I'm glad _to be_ hearing from you" where "to" is part of the infinitive of the verb "to be" an only indirectly linked with the gerund "hearing"